# Responsive images using the cookie and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css, responsive

I've been reading a book called "HTML5 and CSS3 Responsive Web design Cookbook by Benjamine Lagrone" on page 8. The code was already given but the problem is the instruction is not very clear to me. I had seen a similar problem as with the book, link is:

https://keithclark.co.uk/articles/responsive-images-using-cookies/

However, the instruction is also not clear. It does not say what file/s should I create. So I had put all the codes with just 2 file and 3 images. I only know the basics of javascript so I'm a bit confused here.

**Here's my code**
First file: This is Located outside images folder. I named it "index.html"

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Responsive Images Test</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script>
    document.cookie = "device_dimensions=" + screen.width + "x" + screen.height;
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <img src="images/?test.png">
  <!-- the above is equivalent to: <img src="images/index.php?test.png"> -->
</body>
</html>
```

2nd file: I named it "index.php" inside images folder

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Responsive Images Test</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script>
    document.cookie = "device_dimensions=" + screen.width + "x" + screen.height;
  </script>
</head>
<body>


<?php
  $device_width = 0;
  $device_height = 0;
  $file = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];

  if (file_exists($file)) {

    // Read the device viewport dimensions
    if (isset($_COOKIE['device_dimensions'])) {
      $dimensions = explode('x', $_COOKIE['device_dimensions']);
      if (count($dimensions) == 2) {
        $device_width = intval($dimensions[0]);
        $device_height = intval($dimensions[1]);
      }
    }

    if ($device_width > 0) {

      $fileext = pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

      // Low resolution image
      if ($device_width <= 800) {
        $output_file = substr_replace($file, '-low', -strlen($fileext) - 1, 0);
      } 

      // Medium resolution image
      else if ($device_width <= 1024) {
        $output_file = substr_replace($file, '-med', -strlen($fileext) - 1, 0);
      }

      // check the file exists
      if (isset($output_file) && file_exists($output_file)) {
        $file = $output_file;
      }
    }

    // return the file;
    readfile($file);
  }
?>

</body>
</html>
```

what should I do? The images is not visible in the browser to show that it's responsive.

Comment: doctype should be DOCTYPE and I recommend strongly against any use of cookies.. just use media css rules like everyone else :)

Comment: That article is 7 years old, there are much better ways to deal with responsive images in 2018. See [the picture element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/picture) (and the media attribute in particular).

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs — The doctype keyword is case-insensitive.

Comment: "I only know the basics of java" — There's no Java here. The only programming languages involved are JavaScript (no relation) and PHP. (And it is the PHP that your problem is with)

Comment: @Quentin huh weird - I may be outdated then, probably never was case sensitive, I just got tricked into doing capital `DOCTYPE` - thanks for letting me know :)

Comment: @Quentin, it's a mistypo and what I mean was javascript. In regards to your link, is this reliable in server side? There's a part in a book that says the code written could provide a server-side delivery of the properly sized image though it is limited. I am new to learning responsive web design using only css or css3. What is the updated way in creating reaponsive then?

Comment: "is this reliable in server side?" — It's HTML, it's client side. "I am new to learning responsive web design using only css or css3." — You're dealing with a *content* image, that's why I recommended HTML… but your approach is JavaScript/PHP which isn't CSS either. "What is the updated way in creating reaponsive then?"  — For the specific thing you are trying to do … see the link I provided in my previous comment.

Answer (score 1):

The PHP needs to:

1. Output the right content-type header for the image you are loading (e.g `header("Content-Type: image/png")`
2. Output only the HTTP header and the image. You have to remove all the HTML (which will be treated as corrupt image data).